# counting the number of letters in each word of a paragraph python

Tags: python, list, counting, cpu-word, letter

If I need to write a function that reads a large paragraph and prints out how many words there are of each length in the paragraph how would I do so?

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
#split the piece of writing into a list so I can search over every word
#need to find out how to make this not take so long

piece = "hello world"
words = piece.split()

#search over every word, have a variable for each number, check to see length of word and add correspondingly

for word in range(words):
    one = 0
    two = 0
    three = 0
    four = 0
    five = 0
    six = 0
    seven = 0
    eight = 0
    nine = 0
    ten = 0
    eleven = 0
    twelve = 0
    thirteen = 0
    other = 0
    total = 0
    if (len(word) == 1):
        one += 1
        total += 1
    elif (len(word) == 2):
        two += 1
        total += 1
    elif (len(word) == 3):
        three += 1
        total += 1
    elif (len(word) == 4):
        four += 1
        total += 1
    elif (len(word) == 5):
        five += 1
        total += 1
    elif (len(word) == 6):
        six += 1
        total += 1
    elif (len(word) == 7):
        seven += 1
        total += 1
    elif (len(word) == 8):
        eight += 1
        total += 1
    elif (len(word) == 9):
        nine += 1
        total += 1
    elif (len(word) == 10):
        ten += 1
        total += 1
    elif (len(word) == 11):
        eleven += 1
        total += 1
    elif (len(word) == 12):
        twelve += 1
        total += 1
    elif (len(word) == 13):
        thirteen += 1
        total += 1
    else:
        other += 1
        total += 1

#print results
print(f'Proportion of 1- letter words: {one / total * 100}% {one} words')
print(f'Proportion of 2- letter words: {two / total* 100}% {two} words')
print(f'Proportion of 3- letter words: {three / total* 100}% {three} words')
print(f'Proportion of 4- letter words: {four / total * 100}% {four} words')
print(f'Proportion of 5- letter words: {five / total * 100}% {five} words')
print(f'Proportion of 6- letter words: {six / total * 100}% {six} words')
print(f'Proportion of 7- letter words: {seven/ total * 100}% {seven} words')
print(f'Proportion of 8- letter words: {eight / total * 100}% {eight} words')
print(f'Proportion of 9- letter words: {nine / total * 100}% {nine} words')
print(f'Proportion of 10- letter words: {ten / total * 100}% {ten} words')
print(f'Proportion of 11- letter words: {eleven / total * 100}% {eleven} words')
print(f'Proportion of 12- letter words: {twelve / total * 100}% {twelve} words')
print(f'Proportion of 13- letter words: {thirteen / total * 100}% {thirteen} words')
```

I think the two problems are that I don't know how to get the loop to run for the entire length of the paragraph and I don't know how to make the code so that with a large piece of text it doesn't take forever to run.

Answer (score 4):

- try to avoid repeating code. For example, instead of multiple variables it is easier to have a dictionary (e.g., `stats`), incrementing its records on each word (`stats[len(word)] +=` )
- there are a ton of batteries included in Python, which can substantially reduce the amount of code you write. In this case, `defaultdict` and `Counter` might be helpful.

After applying these, you get something like:

```
from collections import Counter

stats = Counter(len(word) for word in paragraph.split())
total_words = sum(stats.values())

for length in sorted(stats.keys()):
    print("proportions of %d words: %f" % (length, stats[length] / total_words))
```

**UPD:** Sidenote: when iterating dictionaries, Python uses only keys. `Counter` subclasses from dictionary, so it shares the same behavior. So, for brevity it is ok to just `for length in sorted(stats):`, but it might look unintuitive for those not familiar with this Python feature. `stats.keys()` leads to the same result but it is more explicit.

Comment: I never knew about this Counter. Thanks for teaching me something new!

Answer (score 0):

## Hello, the code counts all letters, comma, and so on.

```
fname = input('Enter the file name: ')
try:
    f=open(fname)
except:
    print('The file can not be opened')
t=[]
for line in f:
    s=line.split()
    t.extend(s)
h=dict()
for i in t:
    for j in I:
        if j in h:
            h[j]+=1
        else:
            h[j]=1
print(h)
```

Comment: I'd leave the hello off of your heading and include some context on what you are doing. As is, this answer is a bit terse.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).